# Excel vba to select item from dropdown on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, vba, web-scraping

I'm having trouble getting the syntax right to select an item from a dropdown on a webpage. It's to select gender. I think it's something to do with it using javascript. When I do Inspect element on the dropdown I get the following:

```
<table width="100%" style="z-index: auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" oldz="auto"><tbody style="z-index: auto;" oldz="auto">
<tr style="z-index: auto;" oldz="auto">
<td style="width: 100%; z-index: auto;" oldz="auto">
<div class="FBox" style="width: auto; position: relative; z-index: auto;" oldz="auto" outerdiv="Y"><input name="VX_Gender" id="VX_Gender" type="hidden" value="M">
<div class="EditDiv EditDropDown" id="VX_Gender_ext" role="textbox" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" ondrop="return false" origval="Male" hig="1" max="-1" strictselection="Y" focstyle="EditDropDownFoc" isfilter="Y" filterbox="Y" val2="Male" LastTouchType="Y">Male</div>
<script>initDiv('VX_Gender');</script>
</div>
</td>
<td style="white-space: nowrap;"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

When I do the same on a dropdown item I get:

```
<table width="100%" style="z-index: auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" oldz="auto">
<div class="filtermenu" style="left: 271.76px; top: 252.5px; width: 122px; height: auto; margin-top: 0px; display: none; z-index: 1698; -ms-overflow-y: auto; max-height: 67px;" onclick="return filterPopupClick( event );" hovermenu="Y" shrink="Y" unselectable="on" lastfilter="Male">
<div class="bcrow rsel" onmouseover="return fRowHov(this);" value="F" origva="Female" hc="#FFFFFF" fkey="F" frow="Y" fIdx="2">
Fe
<span class="fsr">male</span>
</div>

<div class="bcrow" onmouseover="return fRowHov(this);" value="I" origva="Indeterminate" hc="#FFFFFF" fkey="I" frow="Y" fIdx="-1">Indeterminate</div>

<div class="bcrow" onmouseover="return fRowHov(this);" value="M" origva="Male" hc="#FFFFFF" fkey="M" frow="Y" fIdx="0"><span class="fsr">Male</span></div>

<div class="bcrow" onmouseover="return fRowHov(this);" value="U" origva="Unborn" hc="#FFFFFF" fkey="U" frow="Y" fIdx="-1">Unborn</div>

</div>
```

I've tried various formats in my code but none seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub gender()

Dim URL, PER_ID As String
Dim objShell, ie  As Object
Dim ele As IHTMLElement

'Determine if a specific instance of IE is already open.
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    'Sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    URL = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location

    If URL = "https://protocolshef.syhapp.com:51020/web/faorc.htm" Then   'Identify the existing web page
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next

For Each ele In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
    If ele.ID = "VX_Gender_ext" Then
        ele.innerText = "Female"
        ele.Val2 = "Female"
        Call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("initDiv('VX_Gender');", "JavaScript")
    End If
Next

For Each ele In ie.document.getElementsByName("VX_Gender")
    ele.Value = "F"
    ele.origval = "F"
Next

For Each ele In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
    If ele.ID = "VX_Gender_ext" Then
        ele.innerText = "Female"
        ele.Val2 = "Female"
        Call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("initDiv('VX_Gender');", "JavaScript")
    End If
Next

For Each ele In ie.document.getElementsByName("VX_Gender")
    ele.Type = "text"
    ele.Value = "F"
    ele.origval = "F"
Next  

End Sub
```

Code testing QHarr's suggestion, which unfortunately didn't work.

```
Sub gender()

Dim URL, PER_ID As String
Dim objShell, ie  As Object
Dim x, IE_count As Long
Dim ele As IHTMLElement

'Determine if a specific instance of IE is already open.
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    'Sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    URL = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location

    If URL = "https://protocolshef.syhapp.com:51020/web/faorc.htm" Then   'Identify the existing web page
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next

Set ele = ie.document.querySelectorAll("div[frow=Y]")
ele.Item(1).Selected = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion QHarr. Unfortunately it didn't work. I've added the code as tested above. The system is on a private network so access isn't possible.

Comment: No error message but ele = Nothing, so presumably just nothing found?

Comment: Ah, well spotted. Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. Don't know if it helps but there's another dropdown on the page with frow="Y" in all the items.

Comment: It's in a form. I realised I'd declared element as IHTMLElement instead of object. I've used your code exactly and now I get error 424 Object required at the next line: element.Item(1).Selected = True

Comment: Thanks. That seems to get the NodeList ok but everything I try to get to the element I want causes an unhandled error.For Each ele In elements  If ele.Value = "F" Then ele.Selected = True Next ele (where ele is IHTMLElement. There should only be one in the list so could it be selected directly?

Comment: I get error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method. I tried it with fkey=F and got the same result.

Comment: when I run it to Set elements = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).querySelector("div[fkey=F]"), hoverover on elements shows elements = "[object HTMLDivElement]". Which looks promising.

Comment: Phew - that did it! Thanks so much.

Comment: That's fine, I was wondering how to credit you with the solution on here.

Comment: Glad we got there. I don't like unsolved cases!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging the solution was as follows:

```
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).querySelector("div[fkey=F]").Click
```

A form needed to be navigated and then a CSS selector combination of `div[fkey=F]` to target the element in question.

The selector combination looks for a `div` element with attribute `fkey` whose value is `F`.

Comment: Thanks again QHarr. Couldn't have got there on my own.

Comment: You will next time! CSS selectors are really cool btw. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp